# Azure DB/MSSQL 2017 query performance regression

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure

I have this pretty simple table with 17m records in it:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LineNumbers](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LineDescriptionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProtocolId] [int] NULL,
    [Value] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_LineNumbers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Query to the table with additional join works fine, if there is no `ProtocolId` in it:

```
select top 1
  ln.LineDescriptionId
from LineNumbers ln
join LineDescriptions ld on ld.Id = ln.LineDescriptionId and ld.ProtocolSetId = 25

-- Elapsed time: 00:00:00.1718750
```

Execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJV34gvR7

But when I try to add `ProtocolId` to the field list, query time grows dramatically:

```
select top 1
  ln.ProtocolId
from LineNumbers ln
join LineDescriptions ld on ld.Id = ln.LineDescriptionId and ld.ProtocolSetId = 25

-- Elapsed time: 00:02:19.6464843
```

Execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkG-hyDCQ

Also, this works smooth:

```
select top 1
  (select ProtocolId from LineNumbers where LineNumbers.Id = ln.Id) as ProtocolId
from LineNumbers ln
join LineDescriptions ld on ld.Id = ln.LineDescriptionId and ld.ProtocolSetId = 25

-- Elapsed time: 00:00:00.1718750
```

Tried this queries and variations on Azure DB and local MSSQL 2017. Results are the same. As long as I keep `ProtocolId` out of the field list everything is fine.

Is there some mistake in my data scheme (everything was created via migrations of Entity Framework)?

```html
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LineNumbers](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LineDescriptionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProtocolId] [int] NULL,
    [Value] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_LineNumbers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [IX_LineNumbers_LineDescriptionId]    Script Date: 21.11.2018 10:47:09 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_LineNumbers_LineDescriptionId] ON [dbo].[LineNumbers]
(
    [LineDescriptionId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [IX_LineNumbers_LineDescriptionId_Value]    Script Date: 21.11.2018 10:47:09 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_LineNumbers_LineDescriptionId_Value] ON [dbo].[LineNumbers]
(
    [LineDescriptionId] ASC,
    [Value] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [IX_LineNumbers_ProtocolId]    Script Date: 21.11.2018 10:47:09 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_LineNumbers_ProtocolId] ON [dbo].[LineNumbers]
(
    [ProtocolId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LineNumbers]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_LineNumbers_LineDescriptions_LineDescriptionId] FOREIGN KEY([LineDescriptionId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[LineDescriptions] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LineNumbers] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_LineNumbers_LineDescriptions_LineDescriptionId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LineNumbers]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_LineNumbers_Protocols_ProtocolId] FOREIGN KEY([ProtocolId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Protocols] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LineNumbers] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_LineNumbers_Protocols_ProtocolId]
GO
```

Comment: It might be something with statistics. Two questions to consider: 1. do you have  any `ORDER BY`s in your queries? 2. have you tried with some index hints?

Comment: 1. I'm not using any `ORDER BY` in this queries (the field `ProtocolId` is mentioned only in field list of `SELECT` query, no any additional filters, etc). 2. there wasn't any index hint while I tried this queries, but finally I resolved it by adding index `LineNumbers.LineDescriptionId` include `ProtocolId`.

Comment: yes, that makes sense to have an index on the column you perform join on and then include `ProtocolId` into that index since that way you avoid going to table but getting that column from index directly.

Comment: Understand. It is also means that I have to include `Value` column to this new index if I want to retrieve `Value` like `ProtocolId` (because it works also slow without include for `Value` to index). In other words, I have to include all columns from select list of target table to index when I do `SELECT + JOIN`?

Comment: oh, i've just realized you have `TOP 1`. check this out: http://geekswithblogs.net/Martinez/archive/2013/01/30/why-sql-top-may-slow-down-your-query-and-how.aspx you might want to use `HASH JOIN`. please test and let us know the results here!

Comment: Thanks, I tried `HASH JOIN` without additional index and results are the same: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkHM4gPA7

Comment: i won't pretend i know exact answer why this happens but the thing i'd start with is: why do you have `TOP 1` without any `ORDER BY`? asking that because it implies how would the query optimizer actually order the results and what criteria would make top record actually to be `TOP 1`? and that's probably where the answer is: you would usually put that column into `ORDER BY` and then have (at least) index on it. otherwise, its random and it has to do scans.

Comment: i would definitely like to hear some authoritative answer.

Comment: I added `TOP 1` just to limit query results. Initially, I encountered regression when I added `ProtocolId` to the query which requested only `LineDescriptionId` field (query took 5-10 seconds to run). But when I added `ProtocolId` to field list, query time fell to 40-50 seconds (I was wondered, why is that?) That's why I started to investigate the reason of performance regression, and after I added `TOP 1`, this query took **2-3 minutes** to run.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I solved it by adding nonclustered index on field `LineNumbers.LineDescriptionId` with inclusion of `LineNumbers.ProtocolId`

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_LineNumbers_LineDescriptionId_ProtocolId] ON
    [dbo].[LineNumbers]([LineDescriptionId] ASC)

INCLUDE ([ProtocolId])

WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF,
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

Result:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    ln.ProtocolId
FROM LineNumbers ln
JOIN LineDescriptions ld ON ld.Id = ln.LineDescriptionId AND ld.ProtocolSetId = 25

-- Elapsed time: 00:00:00.1403155
```

Execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Syywn1wRQ

Why does it work that way?

For example, if I'd do similar use case with PostgreSQL then there is no need in any additional indexes at all (beside obvious FK indexes on `ProtocolId` and `LineDescriptionId` fields).